# Какой запрос наиболее быстрый? Какой ключ применить?

Tags: php, mysql

В таблице есть поле `city_id`, нужно перед вставкой записи выполнить проверку, есть ли поле с определенным `city_id`.

Записей в таблице 2000000.

Очень медленно ищет.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sl_cities` WHERE `city_id` = ".$value['id'].";
```

Какой запрос использовать для поиска?

И какой ключ применить для `city_id`?

Примари кей в таблице нет, также значения `city_id` без повторений.

Таблица MyISAM

```
1   city_id int(11)

2   country_id  int(11)

3   region_id   int(11)

4   area    varchar(1024)

5   region  varchar(1024)

6   title   varchar(1024)

7   important   tinyint(4)
```

В дальнейшем выборка будет идти не только по `city_id`, но и по `country_id` и `region_id`.

Comment: @fjghkjg, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Вы же понимаете, что такой запрос не завершится, пока не упрется в дно таблицы? По-хорошему, конечно, движок может проверить поле на то, что оно уникально, но такие вещи предугадывать - это уже искусственный интеллект в БД надо реализовывать.

```
SELECT 1 FROM `sl_cities` WHERE `city_id` = ".$value['id'].";
```

Вернет единицу при первом же совпадении.

Ключ здесь вообще ни при чем, вы путаете ключи и индексы. Ключи позволяют однозначно идентифицировать запись, индексы - осуществлять быстрый поиск по полю. То, что вместе с ключом создается индекс, не значит, что они суть единое целое.

> Примари кей в таблице нет, так же значения city_id без повторений.

Вот вам и primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Интересно, что же у вас за машина такая, что по 2-м миллионам медленно ищет.

А по теме, вообще в таких случаях задача очень просто решается, если у вас архитектура сайта правильно построена (а как мы знаем, это очень важно в таких случаях), я о том, что к вашей этой таблице должна быть только одна сущность в модели, где вы можете оптимизировать (ниже), а если ваша таблица много где используется, то тут печалька.

Как же оптимизировать:

1. Первое: файлы с данными (в данном случае работа с файлами будет быстрее, минусы: если поиск будет не только по ключу, ибо название файла = ключ).
2. SQL дерево: для поиска SQL дерева, наверное, для вас лучший вариант, т.к. деревья создавались для быстрого поиска.
3. Изменить SQL таблицу: иными словами, хэш таблица + таблицы вариантов хэша. Сложность: придумать такой алгоритм, который точно указывал бы на хэш таблицу с вашей сущностью. (Но вполне на костыликах делается.)
4. Помудрить (если есть возможность) с работой SQL сервера, там можно его оптимизировать в некоторых моментах.

**Обновление**

Очень медленно ищет. Какой запрос использовать для поиска?

---

Вот ваши основные тезисы вопроса.

И вообще, я не вижу проблем построить архитектуру по принципу дерева и вставлять туда сколько хотите, есть дерево где поиск всегда будет константный (типа log, ln)

Comment: В 2000 000 записей нужно вставить еще 10 000 000 записей, проверив вначале по ключу

Вы вопрос хоть прочитали?

Comment: Обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sl_cities` WHERE `city_id` = ".$value['id'].";
COUNT
```

считает количество всех записей, удовлетворяющих условие, т.е. сначала выберет все по условию, потом закаунтит, что явно напрягает процессор. И это при каждой итерации вставки записи в бд. Т.е. вставка 10 строк потребует за один запуск срипта  выборки обработать 20кк строк и подсчетать количество 10 раз из 2кк строк - бредятина, утечка памяти, полный ахтунг.

Вполне можно переложить эту заботу на php, все в соответствии с теорией костылизма.
Код в империческом стиле для адаптации под свой движок.

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * (или `city_id`) FROM `sl_cities` WHERE `city_id` = ".$value['id']." LIMIT 0,1");// ищем запись с этим айдишником, лимит 1 для этого и нужен, если она есть - то есть, если нет - то нет, кол-во считать бессмысленно.
$res=mysql_fetch_array($q);
if ($res['city_id']=='') {/*тра та та, айдишник не найден*/}
```

Если принципиально важно посчитать количество записей, можно без лимита в запросе посчитать функцией `mysql_num_rows($q)`, но это медленнее, т.к. все равно выбираются все записи, но в данному случае мы разделяем нагрузку между mysql сервером и php обработчиком.

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * (или `city_id`) FROM `sl_cities` WHERE `city_id` = ".$value['id']);// ищем запись с этим айдишником, лимит 1 для этого и нужен, если она есть - то есть, если нет - то нет, кол-во считать бессмысленно.
$res=mysql_num_rows($q);
if ($res==0) {/*тра та та, записей нет*/}
```

Сейчас у 50% бомбануло при виде SELECT * FROM, но мало кто знает что * напрягает память php, но совершенно не напрягает mysql, тогда как выборка по полю заставляет mysql нагружать проц чуть больше. Выборка по конкретному полю напрягает только mysql (процессор), тут выбирать вам - если грузить память, то *, если проц, то `city_id`. Если столбцов в таблице немного, то вообще без разницы.

Если Вы еще индекс по этому полю построите, то вы сразу решите свою проблему, т.к. 2кк записей не так уж и много, все упрется только в скорость работы скрипта вставки 10кк.

P.S.

> Примари кей в таблице нет, также
> значения city_id без повторений.

В чем проблема выставить примари city_id полю, если оно и так без дубликатов, и автоинкримент - все решится без всех вышеописанных манипуляций. Тогда можно без всяких проверок сразу долбить INSERT'ами (вариант подойдет, если не обращать внимание на вставляемые айдишники).